# PsExec: copying my program not into "system32" folder

Tags: psexec

I can't get PsExec to work. It keeps copying my installer into system32 (where it won't launch). Does anyone know how to copy from the local to the remote computer to a directory that isn't system32? My PsExec command line is

```
psexec \\000.00.00.000 -f -u DOMAIN\meuser -p testpwd -c ..\Installer\test.exe /S
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: It won't launch because I don't have full administrative rights on the computer. It will launch from other directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
net use G: \\remotecomputer\droppoint mypassword /user:myuser@mydomain
xcopy installer G:
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to have admin rights on the target as part of psexec starts up a windows service on the target, and you need admin rights to be able to do that.

psexec copies a psexecsvc file to the admin share and then using remote management starts up a service using that file.  It opens up named pipes and uses that for further communication.  When it's finished it tidies up after itself.

Comment: I can start up the service just fine, I just can't execute the installer from the window folder. If I move it up to the C drive, psexec runs the installer just fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the -w parameter to PsExec to set the working directory for the process on the remote computer. I think the file might still be copied to the system32 directory, but when it is executed the working directory will be the directory specified.

From the PSExec command-line help:

```
-w   Set the working directory of the process (relative to remote computer).
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you XCOPY the installer to a certain place on the remote PC and then PSExec the installer? PSExec shouldn't actually have to copy anything... Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi, we can't use xcopy because we can't always be sure we'll have permissions with windows authentication. With psexec, we can specify a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the PsExec to `C:\Windows\System32` and running it from remote PC require admin rights in the remote PC. However, if we are copying it to some other folder (other than Windows folders), for e-g: `C:\`. In that case, can we try adding a `app.manifest` file to the project and change the execution level, for e-g :

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: This should be posted as comment not answer. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION

I have tried many things, but cant succeed.
 instead COPY something to **`%allusersprofile%`** folder !